# Hacker Rank ginortS.py boolean solution

Tags: python-3.x

How does these codes produce an output of "ginortS1324" with the input of "Sorting1234"?

I do understand the various boolean function, `isdigit()`, `islower()`, `c in '02468'`. The question here is how does all of these work together to produce that output?

`print(*sorted(input(), key=lambda c: (c.isdigit() - c.islower(), c in '02468', c)), sep='')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps very much to print out the keys for the `sorted` function:

```
>>> cs = "Sorted1234"
>>> for c in cs:
...     print((c.isdigit() - c.islower(), c in '02468', c))
...     
... 
(0, False, 'S')
(-1, False, 'o')
(-1, False, 'r')
(-1, False, 't')
(-1, False, 'e')
(-1, False, 'd')
(1, False, '1')
(1, True, '2')
(1, False, '3')
(1, True, '4')
```

The characters in the string are sorted with these tuples as a key. The first element has the highest priority, then comes the second and so forth. Now, if we look, we see, that all the lowercase letters have a `-1` as their first element. This is the lowest number, so they all come first. The second element is `False` for all of them. So now they are sorted alphabetically, because the third element is the character itself.

This explains `deort`.

Now comes the only `0` as the first element, which belongs to `S`.

This extends the explainable string to `deortS`.

Now let's look at the numbers. They are all digits, but `islower()` returns `False`, so the first element in the tuple is `1`. Next they are sorted by the second element; first `False` and then `True`. This gives `1324`.

The resulting string is `deortS1324`.